# Spark: How to use crossJoin

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes. `df1` has 100000 rows and `df2` has 10000 rows.
I want to create a `df3` which is the cross join of the two:

```
val df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
```

This will produce 1 billion rows. Tried to run it locally but it seems that it takes forever. Do you think it can be done locally?

If not which configuration would optimize the time to run this on the cloud?

Comment: plz add a comment if u give a negative vote to understand what i wrote wrong.

Comment: It's not my negative vote, but I suppose people want to know what inside each row and how much memory available on your local hardware at least. Nobody can guess if you can run crossJoin with billion rows on unknown hardware.

Answer (score 10):

First of all I agree with  – Mpizos Dimitris  that you should try to provide every possible details to get the best possible solutions.

But below is a possible but might not be an effective approach.

1.Cache & repartition the small DataFrame df2 . Make sure with repartition the data is evenly distributed across all the worker, so you can use as many tasks as possible. Say you that your cluster has 20 workers with 4 cores per worker. You therefore need  total of 4 x 20 = 80 partitions.

```
df2.repartition(80).cache()
```

2.Perform an action on the DF2 so that the caching occurs before the job starts.Check the SparkUI's Storage tab to make sure that the products DF cache has been distributed on all nodes.

```
df2.show(10)
```

3.Disable broadcast joins temporarily. Broadcast joins don't work well for cartesian products because the workers get so much broadcast data they get stuck in an infinite garbage collection loop and never finish. Remember to turn this back on when the query finishes. you can set the below configuration to disable BC join.

```
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = 0
```

4.Join DF1 with DF2 without using a join condition.

```
val crossJoined = df1.join(df2)
```

5.Run an explain plan on the DataFrame before executing to confirm you have a cartesian product operation.

```
crossJoined.explain
```

Comment: While creating the df1 could you please check if you can create smaller dataframes as per the partition rather than getting the 100000 rows and do a cross join in phases. It’s a costly operation and shuffle will happen. What is your business requirement ? Is cross join necessary can we achieve the same by other means.

Comment: Why do you use 'join' here instead of crossJoin? I tried converting my crossJoin to this method and the join did not have the same result as crossJoin.

Comment: `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = 0`

For Spark 2.* you need to set as below. 

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.partitions.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)`

[src](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#broadcast-hint-for-sql-queries)

Comment: I second the comment about `-1` in Spark 2.x above. It is really important as `0` won't disable it.