# Spark: problem with crossJoin (takes a tremendous amount of time)

Tags: apache-spark

First of all, I have to say that I've already tried everything I know or found on google (Including this [Spark: How to use crossJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684472/spark-how-to-use-crossjoin) which is exactly my problem).

I have to calculate the Cartesian product between two DataFrame - `countries` and `units` such that -

```
A.cache().count()

val units = A.groupBy("country")
    .agg(sum("grade").as("grade"),
      sum("point").as("point"))
    .withColumn("AVR",  $"grade" / $"point" * 1000)
    .drop("point", "grade")


val countries = D.select("country").distinct()
val C = countries.crossJoin(units)
```

`countries` contains a countries name and its size bounded by 150.  `units` is DataFrame with 3 rows - an aggregated result of other DataFrame. I checked 100 times the result and those are the sizes indeed - and it takes 5 hours to complete.

I know I missed something. I've tried caching, repartitioning, etc.
I would love to get some other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally understood the problem  - Spark used too many excessive numbers of partitions, and thus the shuffle takes a lot of time.
The way to solve it is to change the default number -

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 10)
```

And it works like magic.

Comment: Was there any specific logic that made you choose 10 partitions? are you aiming for each partition to be x size

Comment: Actually not. I only understood that the default, which is 200, is pretty high, and I tried to take any smaller value. I was tarted by reducing 200 to 50, and then to 10. The bottom line is it worth a try to change this default configuration when Spark creates too many partitions unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

What is the action you are doing afterwards with `C`?

Also, if these datasets are so small, consider collecting them to the driver, and doing these manupulation there, you can always `spark.createDataFrame` later again.

Update #1:

```
final case class Unit(country: String, AVR: Double)
val collectedUnits: Seq[Unit] = units.as[Unit].collect
val collectedCountries: Seq[String] = countries.collect
val pairs: Seq[(String, Unit)] = for {
  unit <- units
  country <- countries
} yield (country, unit)
```

Comment: It gets stuck when I try to eval C - ```C.cache().count()```. How can I implement your suggestion?

Comment: See update.
I imagine the poor performance is due to having too many partitions, try to coalesce

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. Look at the explain plan and the spark properties, for the amount of data you have mentioned 5 hours is a really long time. My expectation is you have way too many shuffles, you can look at different properties like : spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
2. Instead of doing a cross join, you can maybe do a collect and explore broadcasts
   https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-broadcast-variables/ but do this only on small amounts of data as this data is brought back to the driver.